# is possible to add an img or svg to each selectize option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've a country list with selectize. But I want to also include the flag of each country before the name of the country.

I haven't found any info about this yet. I was wondering if this is possible and how to achieve.

I'm using just html css and js with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's possible to render custom children in selectize according to [this example](https://selectize.dev/docs/demos/email-contact).

Check out the **render** key, you should be able to add an `<img>` tag in there. I made a little example of what I think you're asking for:

html

```
<div class="selectItem">
  <span class="flag"></span>
  <span class="text">Some text</span>
</div>
```

css

```
.selectItem {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flag {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

Simply place the markup in place of the value in the example and that should give you something like what you're looking for I think

Comment: Please don't use external links to show your code, as it's not guaranteed to be static, and not always accessible by all users. Instead, please [edit] your answer to include your code as [formatted text.](/editing-help#code) Answers that are little more than links to external resources may end up being [deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you follow standars for country code, you can use an API, lik this one:

[enter link description here](https://countryflagsapi.com)

Comment: Link-only answers aren't helpful, as links can go dead over time.

Comment: It was not a link only answer, and the link is just an example. The question is also a bit vague.